# Laptop detecting VGA port which isn't there. How to disable it? Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, intel, vga

Is there a way to disable the VGA port permanently, for all users?

My Dell Inspiron 15 (3135) laptop has no VGA port, but System Settings> Screen Display shows the built-in display and a second "Unknown Display". When logged on, the display looks okay, but I keep loosing my mouse off of the side of the screen. I can turn it off in system settings, but it reverts back to dual screen when I reboot.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, the laptop has an Intel Celeron chip and xrandr gives:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+   40.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```